# Need help with: $\lim \sup x_n = \sup{z_k}$ where $z_k$ is a set of limit points

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

This question stems from another [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190049/lim-sup-x-n-supz-k-where-z-k-is-a-set-of-limit-points-for-the-seque), but presents my concern in a more specific way.

There is a theorem saying that:

$\lim \sup x_n = \sup{z_k}$ where $z_k$ is a set of limit points for the sequence $x_n$.

All sets and sequences are real.

Limit point for a sequence is a point such that in any neighborhood of it there is a point from the sequence other than the original point itself.

$$\lim \sup x_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{m \ge n}\{x_m\}=\inf_{n} \sup_{m \ge n}\{x_m\}$$

Now we consider a sequence $1,1,2,\frac{1}{2},...,n,\frac{1}{n},...$, for it $\limsup x_n=\infty$, but there is only one limit point $0$, thus $\sup z_k=0$. So $\limsup x_n \ne \sup z_k$. Is the theorem wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, we have $\limsup x_n=\infty$, so we need to work on an extension of the real line including $\infty$. The usual way of defining a topology on the extended real line is to define rays $(a,\infty]$ as the basic open neighborhoods of $\infty$. In this case, your sequence also has $\infty$ as a limit point, given by the sequence $z_k=k$, and we have $\limsup x_n=\infty=\sup z_k$. The theorem is correct if we read it this way.